# Parsing Strings from a Binary File in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary

I'm using the `Data.Binary.Get` monad to read data from a file in Haskell.  How would I go about converting some Word32 grabbed from getWord32** into a [Char] or String?

I've tried breaking the Word32 into four octets and converting that way, but I'm having trouble getting the conversion working. How would I best convert a Word32 into a string (assuming four characters).

Comment: Does `show` work ? You can see how it's instance is implemented in `base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [utf8-light](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.8/utf8-light-0.4.2/Codec-Binary-UTF8-Light.html#v:w2c) has a function named `w2c` function whose type is:

```
w2c ::Word32 -> Char
```

You can see how it's implemented:

```
w2c :: Word32 -> Char
{-# INLINE w2c #-}
#if defined(__GLASGOW_HASKELL__)
w2c (W32# w) = C#(chr#(word2Int# w))
#else
w2c = unsafeChr . fromIntegral
#endif
```

You can write a wrapper around it:

```
w2s :: Word32 -> String
w2s xs = [xs]
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `show` function since `Word32` has an instance for it. But I guess, it has a performance penalty.